# CSRF prevention filter token generation

Tags: filter, token, csrf

I've a application in which there are hundreds of link to execute. Currently to prevent the application from cross site request forgery (CSRF), I've written a filter to generate token with each state change and storing them in cache. The overhead of this approach / design is the cache size which could get overflow in case of multiple used scenario which my application supports too. I am looking for a approach in which same token can be used again instead of generating it repetitively corresponding to each request.

Comment: that would kinda defeat the purpose, wouldn't it?

Comment: yes it can, but i am not planning to use it in this way only .. some modification in this would be fine

Comment: You can store the token in the $_SESSION

Comment: yes, this one is better @Franco.. thanks